# Meaning of поназакачивать

Tags: значения

A friend on Skype sent me the following message and I don't understand one word of it, nor can I find any of the words in my dictionary:

> я поназакачивал в инете

Comment: Russian language is very flexible with suffixes and prefixes and their abuse is quite common even when it is not really correct. you just need to understand what they(suf/pref) mean in context and learn to cut the root so that you know how to apply them to get a meaning. Admittedly, it can be quite hard here, since the actual root is кач (which is short of (с)качать)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think of it as ***закачивать*** → ***назакачивать***→ ***поназакачивать*** = *закачать очень много всего* (to download/upload lots of stuff). Kind of a made-up word (just for fun) but still undestandable since it uses a familiar base (закачать) and then a moderately popular prefixed extension — not the most popular, but not unheard of(*понаписал* = написал много всего, *понаделал* = наделал много всякого, понаготовил = приготовил много всякой всячины)

**«качать»** is the verb with one of the meanings related to pumping liquid (typically water) through a pipe. Probably that's why with the spread of the internet the verbs **скачать, закачать, выкачать** appeared to express the different shades of "download", "upload" and so on (along with "загрузить" which means to "load something somewhere" in general, be it in memory or from your HDD).

The formation has a slightly playful/negative connotation as if you were implying that you performed an action extensively, way overdoing it, did it in lotsa different ways and without really thinking there is any point in doing so (may imply there is a lot of "results" of your activity left from such spike of productivity).

- *that is not to say that "качать" derivatives never existed before, but certainly could not have been used to express data transfer*

Answer (score 6):

`Закачать` is equal to `Скачать` what means `download`.
`Поназакачивал` is an equivalent of `Много чего скачал` what means `downloaded plenty of ...`.
In some cases it can has a meaning `downloaded too many things`.

Analogs:

```
Заказал - Ordered smth
Поназаказывал - Ordered plenty of smth
```